# How Do I Change The User In VSCode and Link My Github Account?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm using someone else's laptop with vscode, and while I'm able to push to my github repos, it comes up under their name which makes my github account look inactive.

The integrated terminal in VSCode looks like: `Bob's Macbook:(directory name) Bob`

Therefore, when I push to my repos, it appears as if `Bob` is making commits to my repos when it's actually me. As a result, my 'recent activity' chart on my profile doesn't look like I've been committing, which isn't ideal.

I couldn't find where to change the user in VSCode settings, so I figured I'd post it here in case someone ran into the same issue.

How do I get my github username connected to my VSCode terminal?

Comment: You might generate your own rsa key and set it up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an [article on github](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-commit-email-address#setting-your-commit-email-address-in-git) that answered my question. There's just two easy steps in the `setting your commit email in git` section.

All you have to do is first run:

```
git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
```

Don't use quotation marks, just put your desired email in and make sure it's associated with your github account *(Github > Profile > Settings > Email > Add Email)*

Then check to see if it worked with:

```
git config --global user.email
```

Which should return your email. You'll see your next commit in your profile.

As mentioned in the comments below, you should also run that command with `user.name` to change the name attached to the commit.

Comment: You will also want to set `user.name`, or you'll have the wrong name but correct email in the commit objects.

Comment: You should also take in consideration that if you are using the computer of someone else, using the --global flag will change the settings for the whole computer. You can also run it from inside your repo, without the --global flag, and it will only change the settings of the current repo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a mac and I did

git config --global user.email email@example.com

git config --global user.name example.user

I also had to remove github from my keychain